# How to multiply the analyzes according to the modalities of a third variable?

Tags: r, automation, aggregate

I am working on a large database in which I would like to make chain table(x) according to the modalities of a third (and also fourth) variable, and aggregate the results. I'm blocking a bit, I don't know how to do it.

Here's the structure of my dataframe (data) :

```
age   dead     work    sex
56       1       44      M
20       0       20      F
71       0       62      F
26       1       A0      M
44       0       80      F
19       0       01      M
77       0       78      M
51       0       13      F
56       1       Z0      F
```

Each line is an individual. He has an age, he's dead or alive, it has a profession (it's the column work, which contains a code of profession : "02" is scientific, "88" is worker in metallurgy, "A0" is military, etc.) and a gender (male / female).

I simply want to create mortality tables. It's easy with :

```
table(data$age, data$dead)
```

Here's the result on the complete database, for example :

```
 age  dead=0  dead=1
  ..    ....       .
  25    1725       0
  26    3627       1
  27     336       0
  28    3339       1
  30  275648     856
  31   90932     258
  32  120743     268
  33  587954    1023
  36  148610      57
  39    5101       7
  40   15960      43
  41  102273     336
  42  147941     174
  43   69216      43
  44   43178      37
  45    3074       0
  47    1424       1
  48    3471       1
  49   12048       3
  50      85       0
  51   45138     110
  52   84804     147
  53    4614      16
  54   19241      46
  55   86021     160
  ..    ....       .
```

Now, I would like to do that for each category of the variable "work". Manually, it's easy on a specific category, for example the scientifics :

```
table(data$age[data$class=="02"],data$dead[data$class=="02"])
```

I'm searching how to do that automatically :

1) for each category of the work variable. The variable is not continuous (..., 11, 12, 13, 14, 19, 20,...) and there is sometimes letters (A0, Z0) ;

2) and for each category, I would like to differenciate males and females (a table for scientific males AND a table for scientific females) ;

3) Then aggregate the results of the multiple table(data) in a dataframe, where the join is age. So each column would be the number of individuals by age, for a specific sex and profession.

Can you help me ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: it would be easier if you provided your example data.frame in a code, e.g. `data.frame(age=c(56,20,...), dead=c(1,0,...), ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `table()` function can create contingency tables of any number of levels.  You can pass your entire data frame, then flatten and reshape (assuming I've understood correctly).

```
library(tidyr)

table(df) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = age, values_from = Freq)

# A tibble: 36 x 11
   dead  work  sex    `19`  `20`  `26`  `44`  `51`  `56`  `71`  `77`
   <fct> <fct> <fct> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1 0     01    F         0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 2 1     01    F         0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 3 0     13    F         0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
 4 1     13    F         0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 5 0     20    F         0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 6 1     20    F         0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 7 0     44    F         0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 8 1     44    F         0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 9 0     62    F         0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
10 1     62    F         0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# ... with 26 more rows
```

From there you can further split, reshape, or filter as needed.

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(age = c(56L, 20L, 71L, 26L, 44L, 19L, 77L, 51L, 
56L), dead = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), work = structure(c(4L, 
3L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 9L), .Label = c("01", "13", "20", 
"44", "62", "78", "80", "A0", "Z0"), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Tank you, but i don't really understand the code.

If i use your code on table (data), i have an error :
Error in table(megapop) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements.

So I did a table on only 3 dimensions : age, dead, work.
In this case : Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : objet 'age' introuvable.

So I mentionned data$age instead of age, and I have an error : Error in inds_combine(.vars, ind_list) : Position must be between 0 and n.

Sorry, i'm not the best in R :p

What is Freq ? The function of the package DescTools ?

Comment: Ok I understood : 'as.data.frame' name "age" as "Var1". I have to rename it before I use 'pivot_wider'.